# Is it possibile to disable phone traffic while still allowing cellular data traffic?

Tags: cellular-data, iphone

Sometimes (especially when playing games) I absolutely don't want to get incoming phone calls, but I need to use cellular data traffic, thus I can't simply put the phone in airplane mode.

Is it possible to disable phone traffic while still allowing data traffic?

IOS 10.1.1 on iPhone 6s.

P.S. Disabling phone traffic altogether (f.e. by locking the SIM card) and using only WI-FI is not a solution; I explicitly need *cellular* data traffic.

P.P.S. I know I can simply reject an incoming call; but this is often enough to create troubles in a game (and the phone call also causes the data connection to drop briefly, which for some multiplayer games equals to an instant loss).

Comment: Untested - but did you try Do Not Disturb? You can get to it from the Control Centre, just swipe up from outside the bottom of the screen area, it's the 'moon' symbol.

Comment: It only rejects calls when the phone is locked; if it's unlocked and/or there is an app running in foreground, the incoming call still pops up.